# Code seems to work even though a semicolon is missing

Tags: javascript

I have a browser javascript that extracts data from a table in a web page and creates hidden fields in a form. Below is an excerpt of the code:

```
var allRows = table.childNodes;
for (var i = 1 ; i < allRows.length ; i++) {
    var rowCells = allRows[i].childNodes;
    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    var valueString = computeValue();
    newInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    newInput.setAttribute("name", "timePair" + rowCells[j].getAttribute('id'))   /* This line is missing a ; */
    newInput.setAttribute("value", valueString);
}
```

As you can see, one function call is missing a semicolon, but the code is working anyway, with no errors in neither Internet Explorer nor Firefox.

I checked the javascript grammar and it looks like this shouldn't be allowed.

Why don't I get an error?

Comment: Because semicolons are optional [MDN Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

Comment: Just as @epascarello said, a new line (return) states that the code has ended, and semicolons are optional. I tend to use them just in case.

Comment: even those who dont know about java script  know that "semicolons are optional in javscript"

Comment: There's a feature called [ASI](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9) in JS, though sometimes you'll get unexpected results if you're going to omit the semicolons..

Comment: especially risky with minification when omitting them and relying on ASI.

Comment: @Radio: Not really. Minifiers that don't understand ASI aren't worth using.

Comment: true! i should of said tacky minification.

Comment: @Klas: Here's a good article that gives a balanced overview of ASI concerns. http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript features **Automatic Semicolon Insertion**:

http://jamesallardice.com/understanding-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-in-javascript/

This isn't always a good thing, for example:

```
return
{
    foo: function() {}
}
```

ASI will kick in at the return line and return void. Quite a common JS gotcha... especially for those more familiar with more "formal" languages, where a missing semicolon leads to a compilation error.

Importantly:

> Note that JavaScript does not treat every line break as a semicolon:
>   it usually treats line breaks as semicolons only if it can’t parse the
>   code without the semicolons.

Quote source: [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch02s05.html)